# A playbook with two roles: running role B complains with role A's code which successfully ran

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am experiencing a strange behavior: when I run role B, it complains role A's code which I can successfully run! I have reproduced this to this minimal example:

```
$ cat playbooka.yml 

- hosts:
    - host_a

  roles:
    - role: rolea
      tags:
        - taga
    - role: roleb
      tags:
        - tagb
```

I have tagged two roles because I want to selectively run role A or role B, they consist simple tasks as shown below in this minimal example:

```
$ cat roles/rolea/tasks/main.yml

- name: Get service_facts
  service_facts:

- debug:
    msg: '{{ ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] }}'

- when: ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"
  meta: end_play

$ cat roles/roleb/tasks/main.yml

- debug:
    msg: "I am roleb"
```

The preview confirms that I can run individual roles as specified by tags:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooka.yml -t taga -D -C --list-hosts --list-tasks

playbook: playbooka.yml

  play #1 (host_a): host_a  TAGS: []
    pattern: ['host_a']
    hosts (1):
      3.11.111.4
    tasks:
      rolea : Get service_facts TAGS: [taga]
      debug TAGS: [taga]

$ ansible-playbook playbooka.yml -t tagb -D -C --list-hosts --list-tasks

playbook: playbooka.yml

  play #1 (host_a): host_a  TAGS: []
    pattern: ['host_a']
    hosts (1):
      3.11.111.4
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: [tagb]
```

I can run role A OK:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooka.yml -t taga -D -C

PLAY [host_a] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [3.11.111.4]

TASK [rolea : Get service_facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [3.11.111.4]

TASK [rolea : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [3.11.111.4] => {
    "msg": "running"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
3.11.111.4               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But when I run role B, it complains the code in role A which I just successfully ran!

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooka.yml -t tagb -D -C

PLAY [host_a] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [3.11.111.4]
ERROR! The conditional check 'ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'services'

The error appears to be in '<path>/roles/rolea/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- when: ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes. If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes. For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

I have two questions:

- Why role A's code should be involved at all?
- Even it gets involved, `ansible_facts` has `services`, and the service is "running" as shown above by running role A.

PS: I am using the latest Ansible 2.10.2 and latest python 3.9.1 locally on a MacOS. The remote python can be either 2.7.12 or 3.5.2 (Ubuntu 16_04). I worked around the problem by testing if the dictionary has the `services` key:

```
ansible_facts.services is not defined or ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"
```

but it still surprises me that role B will interpret role A's code and interpreted it incorrectly. Is this a bug that I should report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [notes in `meta` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html):

> Skipping meta tasks with tags is not supported before Ansible 2.11.

Since you run ansible 2.10, the `when` condition for your `meta` task in `rolea` is always evaluated, whatever tag you use. When you use `-t tagb`, `ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]` does not exist as you skipped `service_facts`, and you then get the error you reported.

You can either:

- upgrade to ansible 2.11 (might be a little soon as I write this answer since it is not yet available over pip...)
- rewrite your condition so that the `meta` task skips when the var does not exists e.g.

  ```yaml
  when:
    - ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] is defined
    - ansible_facts.services["amazon-ssm-agent"]["state"] != "running"
  ```

The second solution is still a good practice IMO in whatever condition (e.g. share your work with someone running an older version, running accidentally against a host without the agent installed....).

One other possibility in your specific case is to move the `service_facts` tasks to an other role higher in play order, or in the `pre_tasks` section of your playbook, and tag it [`always`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never). In this case the task will always play and the fact will always exists, whatever tag you use.

Comment: You are right that the problem is with `meta`. When I replace `meta` with debug as a test, there is no such a problem. This is a difficult problem, thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: Instead of end_play, I find I can use fail: which does not have the problem.

Comment: @puravidaso @Zeitounator In my case, I am using the same version and not using `meta` but still, the condition in `when` not working. eg. `when: foo is defined`. I did not define the `foo` anywhere but still, the role is executing successfully. Any suggestion.

Comment: This looks like a totally different problem which should have its own [mcve](/help/mcve) pushed to a new question.